# LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer does not work

Tags: solr, indexing

We have overriden the default mapping by adding:

```
<indexConfigurations>
 <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="vehiclename" returnType="string" indexType="string">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
            </fieldNames>
       </fieldMap>
 </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
</indexConfigurations>
```

However, while querying on this field, it is case sensitive.
Kindly help

Comment: Are you lowercasing your queries against this field?

Comment: Yes.
searchKeyword = searchKeyword.ToLower();
predicates = predicates.And(item => item.VehicleName.Contains(searchKeyword)

Comment: Does it help if you add settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" to the <field> element? (rebuild the index after the change)

Comment: What is `indexType="string"`? Try to change your field parameters to `<field type="System.String" fieldName="vehiclename" returnType="string" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED">`, rebuild index and check in solr browser if your field values are stored in lower case.

Comment: @Gatogordo and x3mxray

I checked with both the changes but the field is not lowercased

My config:
<field type="System.String" fieldName="vehiclename" returnType="string" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>

Comment: keen to know if you were able to resolve this issue, and what was the solution?